# RTK Listener middleware, how to test?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I am trying the brand new listener middleware from redux-toolkit w/ React and Typescript !
I've done some good stuff with it, but now, I would like to push it to next level and try to cover my logic with some tests.

Thus, I was wondering if a test strategy has been documented somewhere. I made some experiments, and the best way to test my logic in isolation is to split my effect logic from the `listenerMiddleware.startListening` function. Here is an exemple :

```js
// effects.ts
export const oidcCallBackSideEffect = async (action, listenerApi) => {
  // some async logic here
};
```

```js
// slice.ts
import { myEffectLogic } from './effects';
import { listenerMiddleware } from 'some/path/to/my/middleware/declaration';

// ...

// Register listener middleware effects
listenerMiddleware.startListening({
  actionCreator: mySlice.actions.foo,
  effect: myEffectLogic,
});
```

In this way, I can create a unit test dedicated to my effect. The main issue with this approach is I do not manage well types (for Typescript).

I was also thinking about another approach with those tests, and apply the React test vision. Indeed, instead of tryping doing some unit test with mocking every object in my effect (as listenerApi.dispatch), let the effect be, register the effect through `listenerMiddleware.startListening`, dispatch the action in order to trigger the effect (in my previous example : `mySlice.actions.foo`), and test the results on my store, in the same way we test our slices by the way.

Let me know your approach about those tests :)
Best regards !
Twisky

Answer (score 0):

For integration testing, I use the full creation of a store (using [redux-mock-store](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store)).

Here is some example that I wrote from the top of my head:

```js
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';

describe(`middleware`, () => {
  it(`expects some side effect`, () => {
    const store = configureStore({
      reducer: {
        [mySlice.name]: mySlice.reducer,
      },
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(listenerMiddleware.middleware),
    });

    store.dispatch(mySlice.actions.foo as unknown as AnyAction);

    expect(selectSomething(store.getState())).toEqual('some-value');
  });
});
```

In the case of an async side effect, you can dispatch another action when that effect is completed or wait for your state to change to a different value.

If you are already using `react-testing-library` you can probably use its `waitFor` method

```js
await waitFor(() => expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining([expect.objectContaining({type: 'someAction'})]));

// or using a selector

await waitFor(() => expect(selectSomeValue(store.getState())).toEqual('someValue'));
```

Comment: As a side note, what I sometimes do instead of using the redux-mock-store is to assert on state changes. That way it becomes a full integration test and I can create a real store instead of a mock one.

Comment: Also, for those that want to dig deeper, my real world use case was to use RTK with MSW to mock API calls. I have created a gist show casing how I tested my side effect for "clearing a selected job" when user settings have changed on the server. https://gist.github.com/srosato/8be5d2c06f5bff15342559ae58d5de76